# Can I modify OpenGL texture parameters between draw calls?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, textures

Working with OpenGL ES 2 in iOS, I have a texture in that gets used in multiple layers.  I'd like now to render it slightly differently in one of the layers, without replicating the texture itself.

I originally created the texture as such, using data in my_texture_data.  This works fine.

```
GLuint lTexId;
glGenTextures(1, &lTexId);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, lTexId);

// use linear filtering
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, my_texture_data);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

I'd like to use nearest neighbor sample in one of the layers.  Is it possible (and if so, how) to simply switch the filtering mode between draw calls?  I tried adding this, just before the draw call that draws each object

```
        /* Excerpt from common code block used to render texture in all layers */
        /* NEW CODE BLOCK */
        if (use_nearest) {
            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
            GLuint tex_id = getTextureId(); // a function to get original texture ID
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_id);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
            GLuint lastError = glGetError();
            if (lastError != 0) {
                printf("GLERROR: %i", lastError);
            }
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        }
        else {
            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
            GLuint tex_id = getTextureId(); // a function to get original texture ID
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_id);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            GLuint lastError = glGetError();
            if (lastError != 0) {
                printf("GLERROR: %i", lastError);
            }
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        }
        /* END NEW CODE */


        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, _IndexCount, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

The attempted solution isn't working.  There are no GL errors, but the filtering mode stays as originally set when the texture was created.

I saw a potential answer in [OpenGL: Reusing the same texture with different parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19634258/opengl-reusing-the-same-texture-with-different-parameters), but right now I need a quick solution that doesn't require code refactoring.

A comment in that answer indicated "you can change the texture parameter whenever you need to do so" - I just don't seem to be doing it correctly.

Any suggestions on *how* to change the parameters / what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can certainly change the parameters before each draw call. Hard to tell what could be wrong from what you posted here. One thing that looks suspicious is that you unbind the texture at the end of this code. You will still need it bound for the draw call. Also, you're changing the active texture unit, and I can't tell if that matches how you use the texture units in the rest of the code. Also, you won't see a massive difference between nearest and linear sampling unless the texture is substantially magnified.

Comment: @Reto yes this is to handle highly magnified cases.